Skitel's noncommutative algebra based algorithm variation question
In Cryptanalysing variants of_Stickel's key agreement_scheme original attack against Stikel's key agreement and of some variants are presented.
The method is to find matrices $X$,$Y$ such that $XA=AX$, $YB=BY$ and $U=XWY$ and perform algebraic manipulations to get a system of linear equations that allows to recover the shared secret.
The original Stikel's key exchange is similar in concept to the ordinary Diffie-Hellman key agreement, in particular the operation to get the intermediate value of Alice or Bob the following expressions are used:
$A,B,W\in GL(n,q)$
$AB\neq BA$
$U=A^lWB^m$
From these done both by Alice and Bob a common secret can be agreed, $l,m\in\mathbb{N}$ are the private key of Alice, similarly for Bob.
The method to break this scheme is to find matrices $X$,$Y$ such that $XA=AX$, $YB=BY$ and $U=XWY$ and perform algebraic manipulations to get a system of linear equations that allows to recover the shared secret.
In particular $X^{-1}$ is used to get rid of the multivariate equations in $U=XWY$, not solvable by Gaussian elimination, so $U=XWY$ is transformed into $X^{-1}U=WY$, which is now solvable by Gaussian elimination as there's no product of matrices as unknowns.
The proposed variant is similar but changing the intermediate value, $U$ or $V$:
$A,B,W\in GL(n,q)$
$AB\neq BA$
$U=A^lWB^m+A^pWB^q$
From this equations a key agreement is done almost the same way, $l,m,p,q\in \mathbb{N}$ are the private key of Alice, similarly for Bob.
The question is there's no necessarily a $U=XWY$ for this construction. We can try to find $U=X_1WY_1+X_2WY_2$, but not as a system of linear equations as the inverse of $X_1$ trick does not work since the second term of the addition remains a product of two unknown matrices, so not solvable as a linear system.
So the question is if being $U=A_1WB_1+A_2WB_2$, how many, if any, solutions in the form $U=XWY$ there are and if any if it's cryptographycaly relevant or a side case which can be considered irrelevant. $X$, $A_1$ and $A_2$ commute pairwise the same as $Y$, $B_1$ and $B_2$.

First we must ensure $U$ is in $GL(p,q)$. Then just try to solve the overdetermined system of equations $X_1A=AX_1$, $YB=BY$ and $X_1U=WY$. If the system of equations is inconsistent there's no solution of the form $U=XWY$.
